# Error in RDLC REPORT - An error occurred during local report processing

Tags: sql, asp.net, rdlc

When i use RDLC report i am stuck with a error...An error occurred during local report processing..

```
ReportViewer1.Reset();
DataTable dt = GetData(Convert.ToDateTime(datefrm), Convert.ToDateTime(dateto), acode, qutono, brcodde);
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";

    int n = 5;

    ReportParameter[] parms = new ReportParameter[n];
    parms[0] = new ReportParameter("DateFrom", datefrm);
    parms[1] = new ReportParameter("DateTo", dateto);
    parms[2] = new ReportParameter("Ac_Code", acode);
    parms[3] = new ReportParameter("QuotNo", qutono);
    parms[4] = new ReportParameter("Br_Code", brcodde);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: `LocalReport.ReportPath` should be a physical path to your rdlc file. You should map the file to the server path using `Server.MapPath` like this `this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report1.rdlc")`;